# I am unable to find Device Registrarion

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to install google assistant on my raspberry pi 3.I am following google assistant SDK for device but I am unable to see the device registration in my Action on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new project, you will see a variety of potential templates. Select **skip** and select the **Device Registration** section in **Advanced Options** in the sidebar.

[image]